# Suggest best way to do this approval workflow for share point form library to send email to the user

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2010

I have created the Info path form.

Once the new form created i need to send the email to users which the user selected in the people picker field.

Is that possible to do this using Designer,or VS 2010.

Give some reference to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/817c0905-be9c-4b69-aee6-1c5043fc835c/